# Angular with Wordpress API and JWT Authentication not Working properly in code even though It Works on PostMan

Tags: angular, wordpress-rest-api, jwt, windows-hosting

I'm facing the below error. I tried multiple solutions but adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to **web.config** does not alter the outcome in a  positive way.

On the other hand, I used PostMan, as a test alternative, and it works flawlessly.

Based on the above evidence, I'm thinking the error is on the authentication code somewhere.

Here's the authentication function snippet.

```
    auth() {
    this.http.post('http://*****.*****.com/two/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
      username: this.user.login,
      password: this.user.password
    }).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data['token']) {
        this.token = data['token'];
        this.tokenChange.emit(this.token);
      }
    });
}
```

Setup:
Windows Server shared-hosting(godaddy)
Angular 7.0.4, 
Wordpress with "JWT Authentication for WP-API" plugin.

*Figure 1. The JS console showing the error. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not the problem as I tested it on PostMan and it works normally*.
[image: Angular and Wordpress error with JWT authentication plugin]

Comment: CORS is only enforced in the browser, which is why it works in Postman. You need to ensure your backend sends the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: Without adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the local web.config, the api works normally when retrieving `posts`. If I add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to web.config, (<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>), I'm unable to retrieve `posts` and `authenticate`. And, it throws an error of `Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin are not allowed`

Comment: The message in your image implies it's not receiving that header. If you check in the browser developer tools network tab, and find the failed requests, is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` actually being sent on the response?

Comment: Usually, if I add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` explicitly to web.config, I get the following error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://******.******.com/two/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed`